# PHP AJAX JSON iteration

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am familiarizing myself with ajax and json.

My page is addAccount.php and inside, I have a FORM with the INPUTs below:

```
 <input type="text" id="partnerCode" />
 <input type="button" id="pCodeSearch" value="Search" />
```

I have a JavaScript page called global.js the gets the information:

```
 $('input#pCodeSearch').on('click' , function()
 {
   var partnercode = $('input#partnerCode').val();
   if($.trim(partnercode) != '')
   {
     $.post('api/pCodeSearch.php', {partnercode: partnercode}, function(data)
     {
       $('div#partner-data').text(data);
     });
   }
 });
```

In the above code, you will see the processing page called pCodeSearch.php.  Here is that code:

```
 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['partnercode']) === true && empty($_POST['partnercode']) === false)
   {
     require "../include/database.php";
     require "../include/sessions.php";

     $search = "SELECT FULL_NAME, PARTNER_CODE from partner WHERE PARTNER_CODE = '"htmlentities(stripslashes(trim($_POST['partnercode'])))."'";

     $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $search); // $dbc is the connection string

     if(mysqli_num_rows($query) !== 0)
     {
       $out = array();
       while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
       {
         $out[] = $row;
       }
       echo json_encode($out);
       mysqli_free_result($query);
     }
     else
     {
       echo 'Partner not found';
     }
   }
 ?>
```

With all of the above code, I can display in a DIV tag called #partner-data, as you saw in my JavaScript code above.

But this is the output:

```
 [{"FULL_NAME":"PARTNER SA","PARTNER_CODE":"0000011182"}]
```

I would like to echo out just PARTNER SA and 0000011182.

I attempted this on my JavaScript page:

```
 $.each(data, function(index, item)
 {
   $('<div>').
     attr('value', item.PARTNER_CODE).
     text(item.FULL_NAME).
     appendTo($('#partner-data'));
 });
```

But nothing returns to the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop seems correct *if* the json string that came back from php has been parsed.

As you see a string in your first attempt, my guess would be that it is not parsed, so you would need:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(obj, function(index, item) {
   $('<div>').
     attr('value', item.PARTNER_CODE).
     text(item.FULL_NAME).
     appendTo($('#partner-data'));
});
```

You can also tell jquery to do that automatically using the 4th parameter of [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to specify the type of the returned data:

```
$.post('api/pCodeSearch.php', {partnercode: partnercode}, function(data) {
    // your original $.each() loop
  }, 'json');
   ^^^^^^^^ here
```

Comment: Thank you, good sir.  I attempted the first piece of code you provided and I was successfully retrieving the necessary data.  In the text portion, I did: text(item.FULL_NAME+" , "+item.PARTNER_CODE) and was able to print both to the screen.  I am not exactly sure what the second piece of code (you provided) does.  I will attempt it nonetheless.  Thank you thank you.

Comment: @HoodCoderMan It tells jQuery to parse the json as soon as it comes in, so your `data` variable will be an object and you can use that directly in the loop you posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$('div#partner-data').text(data);
```

try:

```
 $('div#partner-data').text(data.d.["FULL_NAME"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i m gonna to help you :) ,

First set the correct content type for that json response,,

so write like this :

```
header('Contenty-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($out);
```

then on client side response handling function will look like :-

```
$('input#pCodeSearch').on('click' , function()
 {
   var partnercode = $('input#partnerCode').val();
   if($.trim(partnercode) != '')
   {
     $.post('api/pCodeSearch.php', {partnercode: partnercode}, function(data)
     {
        // $('div#partner-data').text(data);
        // Because data value is json, and actually it is returing a array of objects
        // so

        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

            currect_object = data[i];
            $('div#partner-data').append(current_object.FULL_NAME + '\t' + current_object.PARTNER_CODE + '\n');  
           // here you can also create an templete and can use that like 
           //  output_html = mytemplete(current_object.FULL_NAME, current_object.PARTER_CODE);
           //  $('div#partner-data').append(output_html);  

        } // __iterate to all array of objects

     }); // __post
   } // __if
 });
```

and i don't think you need that jquery each, There may be some syntex error, because i did not check that, :) Thanks,